# Triple Integral Proof

Tags: calculus, multiple-integral

Our professor gave us a question to try by ourselves at home, saying that $a_1 \leq x \leq a_2,\;b_1 \leq y \leq b_2,\;c_1 \leq z \leq c_2$ how would you show $$\iiint \alpha\;dxdydz = \alpha(a_2-a_1)(b_2-b_1)(c_2-c_1)$$ I solved it using iterated integrals but he said to attempt it without it and use the definition of a triple integral. I've been stumped at how to approach this, how would I start off?

Comment: This is by definition the mass of a cuboid of uniform density $\alpha$ with volume defined by all the points $(x,y,z)\in[a_1,a_2]\times[b_1,b_2]\times[c_1,c_2]$. Using the regular formula for mass gives $m=\rho\cdot v=\alpha(a_2-a_1)(b_2-b_1)(c_2-c_1)$ as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Given positive integers $p,q,r$, we take partitions of the three intervals by putting
$$
x_j=a_1+\frac{j(a_2-a_1)}{p},\ \ \ 
y_k=b_1+\frac{k(b_2-b_1)}{q},\ \ \ 
z_\ell=c_1+\frac{\ell(c_2-c_1)}{r}.
$$
Then the Riemman sums for your integral are 
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^q\sum_{\ell=1}^r\,f(x_j,y_k,z_\ell)\,\Delta x\,\Delta y\,\Delta z
&=\sum_{j=1}^p\sum_{k=1}^q\sum_{\ell=1}^r\alpha\,\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}p\right)\,\left(\frac{b_2-b_1}q\right)\,\left(\frac{c_2-c_1}r\right)\\ \ \\
&=\alpha\,\left( {a_2-a_1}\right)\,\left( {b_2-b_1}\right)\,\left( {c_2-c_1}\right).
\end{align}
Then we need to take the limit as $p,q,r$ go to infinity, but the sums are already constant so the limit is the same.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for iterated integrals
\begin{eqnarray*}
\iiint \alpha\;dxdydz =  \alpha \int_{a_1}^{a_2} dx \int_{b_1}^{b_2} dy \int_{c_1}^{c_2} dz = \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Isn't what you've done an iterated integral too? I'm confused

Comment: An iterated integral is integrals inside integrals see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_integral

Your integral "de-couples" into a product of independent single variable integrals
\begin{eqnarray*}
\alpha  \left( \int_{a_1}^{a_2} dx  \right) \left( \int_{b_1}^{b_2} dy \right)   \left( \int_{c_1}^{c_2} dz \right). 
\end{eqnarray*}